# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError" while trying to import pandas

Tags: python

I am trying to make some plots for data representation, but for this, I will have to use pandas. While trying to import pandas, it always shows up with an error. Take a look

I've already tried downloading pandas from different places, and it still doesn't work. It works for other students trying to perform the same task. I am using PyCharm, but I've also tried Sublime text, jupyter notebooks, spyder. I also asked my own ICT support expert, but he couldn't find the problem either.

```
# Import

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

auto_prices = pd.read_csv('/Users/Justin/Desktop/Data.csv')

def clean_auto_data(auto_prices):
    'Function to load the auto price data set from a .csv file'
```

This is what it shows up with:

```
/Users/Justin/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/bin/python /Users/Justin/PycharmProjects/Test/Test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Justin/PycharmProjects/Test/Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: just running `pip install pandas` from the terminal (command line) should do it. Did you try?

Comment: Check `pip list` for installed libs like pandas etc + additional check if your venv is used by your ide like pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try your code from a terminal. Open a terminal and activate your python virtual environment by sourcing the python activate file with cmd

```
. /Users/Justin/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/bin/activate
```

Now check if the modules you want to use are already installed by checking the response from `pip list`.

If something is missing install the required libs by `pip install pandas numpy matplotlib seaborn`.

Check again `pip list`. Now all libs should be installed.

Run python `/Users/Justin/PycharmProjects/Test/Test.py`. The error should be solved.

Last but not leas check in pycharm (in your project settings) if the correct environment is used.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I also found another way to fix this issue in performing your solution. I saw that in PyCharm, if there is an issue, it will show up with a red light bulb above the code in which you select. In my case, it gave me the option to download the packages I needed, strait from PyCharm. One click!